# Prevent Unity Dash from searching  specific hard drive

Tags: unity-dash, zeitgeist

I have a hard drive that is exclusively used for storage of music, pictures, movies and that sort of thing. It contains no system files.

To conserve power and reduce noise, I have set it to spin down after a certain period of time has passed without any activity. The problem is that whenever I search for anything in the Dash, the hard drive spins back up.

I have tried to configure Zeitgeist to not include the hard drive when recording activity[1], but this policy does not seem to be respected. Even though my entire music library is located on the hard drive, I can still search through it via the Dash, even after deleting all history.

How can I prevent the Dash from accessing this hard drive entirely?

[1]In the 'Files' tab there is a box named "Do not record activity in the following folders". I have included the hard drive's mount point here.

Comment: This unanswered question would be addressing Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL or another Ubuntu version which reached EOL sooner. `zeitgeist` is no longer an active package and it's website: http://zeitgeist-project.com/ is abandoned. The original product has been absorbed into `GNOME Activity Journal`. VTC as `not reproducible.